# what is nb_conda_kernels equivalent for python 3.9+?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, conda

`conda install nb_conda_kernels`  in the base environment throws the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - nb_conda_kernels -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']

Your python: python=3.9
```

what do i need to do to make all the kernels visible to the jupyter notebook I'm firing from the `base` environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conda Forge builds it for Python 3.9, so

```
conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda_kernels
```

Given the solve results, I'd guess your current channel configuration is **defaults** only, so it might be worth noting that sometimes mixing **conda-forge** and **anaconda** channels can get hairy (dynamic library issues) and make solves slow. An alternative is to create a new env dedicated for your Jupyter infrastructure (like [what the `nb_conda_kernels` package hints at](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#installation)) and get all of that from Conda Forge.

#### Steps for Dedicated Jupyter Environment

```
# create environment only from Conda Forge
conda create -n jupyter --override-channels -c conda-forge jupyter nb_conda_kernels python=3.9

# activate
conda activate -n jupyter

# set env-specific channel options
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
```

Then always launch Jupyter (e.g., `jupyter notebook`) from this activated env.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @merv .. 'An alternative is to create a new env dedicated for your Jupyter infrastructure (like what the nb_conda_kernels package hints at) and get all of that from Conda Forge.'
- can you please explain more? Do i make an environment where i want to fire jupyter from and for that env keep the default channel conda-forge?

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder yes, exactly that. I added an example for how to set up an environment with **conda-forge** prioritized, but without adding **conda-forge** to the global channels configuration.

Comment: Can you please help at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210097/is-it-advisable-to-not-mix-packages-in-a-conda-environment-from-different-conda as well?